# Put circle top div position center

Tags: html, css

I need to replicate this.
What is the best way to add a cirle like this image with css?

thanks [image]

Comment: show what you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what google say : https://fellowtuts.com/html-css/css-shapes-circle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example, I think you can do it a bit better if you take time ;).

if you want a full circle just make the (border-radius : 50%) for all corners instead of only top.

cheers

```css
.circle{
height: 50px;
width: 100px;
border-top-left-radius:90px;
border-top-right-radius:90px;
background-color: green;
color:white;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
}

.square{
width:500px;
height: 300px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="circle">1/12</div>
  <div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added your numbered tab into the :before tab, so that it will always be attached to your div.

```css
.square {
position: relative;
width: 80%;
height: 300px;
background-color: white;
margin: 60px auto;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.square:before {
content:'1/12';
position: absolute; 
top: -35px; 
height: 65px;
width: 65px;
border-radius: 50%;
z-index: -1;
transform: translate(-50%);
left: 50%;
background: #4ED3CE;
color: #fff;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="square">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve half circle with following code, then you can customize it yourself

```css
 

div {
  background: #9e978e;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  height: 45px;
  width: 90px;
}

.right,
.left {
  height: 90px;
  width: 45px;
}

.top {
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
}

.right {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 90px;
  border-top-right-radius: 90px;
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 90px;
}

.left {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
  border-top-left-radius: 90px;
}

.rotate {
  animation: 1s linear infinite rotate;
  position: relative;
  top: $size * -1;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="rotate top"></div>
```